# Why Rasa NLU uses SVM rather than LSTM?

Tags: rasa-nlu

I am new to machine learning.

I read in few blogs that says RASA NLU uses SVM to classify the word embeddings to classify the intent. But recently my developer says LSTM is better to use rather than a SVM. Can I use rasa nlu with LSTM. Was that a good approach?

I currently use spacy_sklearn to train my model on Rasa nlu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rasa NLU doesn't just use an SVM it offers [multiple pipelines](https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/choosing_pipeline/) that use multiple algorithms.

Here is some information on [Rasa's TensorFlow pipeline](https://medium.com/rasa-blog/supervised-word-vectors-from-scratch-in-rasa-nlu-6daf794efcd8). In that article they also link to another article that explains how the SVMs are an ["embarrassingly good baseline"](https://twitter.com/ml_review/status/948570915746574336)

Here's a blog post on [how to choose the right pipeline](https://blog.rasa.com/rasa-nlu-in-depth-part-1-intent-classification/) in Rasa NLU that they wrote.

I saw that you also asked this question in the [Articulate Gitter](https://gitter.im/samtecspg/articulate?at=5cc01cd0b489bb6ed7b6e778). Sorry for not replying there. Articulate supports any pipeline that Rasa does and our latest releases default to Rasa's TensorFlow pipeline.

It is not possible to say that LSTMs are always better than SVMs. Though you could Google around for [others opinions.](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Which_is_more_accurate_Neural_Networks_NNsor_support_vector_machineSVM) Is your current solution failing to properly classify the intents? If so, then try a different pipeline. If not, then moving to a newer/fancier technology just for the sake of it doesn't make sense.